# Email trigger AutoHotKeys to run?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, autohotkey

I am learning to use AutoHotKeys and I have a repetitive task that happens on every email. But it involves a different program outside of google. So I am wondering if someone can help with this. My research is showing I can use HotStrings but never used those and How would I have that trigger AutoHotKeys to turn on?

I am hoping there is just a command I can use but if not I just need to figure out a way to trigger the program to run. I am happy to import my Gmail into outlook or any mail program to make this work.

Comment: It makes sense to describe your workflow more closely. What the tasks you trying to perform? Why they can not be accomplished with the pure Google Apps Script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and no code this is a Hotkey:

```
!^a:: ; Alt+Ctrl+a
...Do some stuff
Return
```

This is a Hotstring:

```
::aye::
...Do some stuff
Return
```

Notice how the Hotstring is preceded by two colons and the Hotkey is not. Hotstrings are usually used for auto-replace when typing, such as typos or automatically expanding a shorthand notation to a full string. Example:

```
::tysm::thank you so much
```

Factually you can use them to fire a script too though like the first example above of a Hotstring. Hope that makes sense :)